# Take objects which attributes contains any element of array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to take those members whose name contains at least one of strings in array.

```
string[] words=content.TrimEnd().TrimStart().Split(' ');
```

So I want to choose that members which names contains any string from these `words` array, something like this

```
context.Members.Where(p.Name.Contains(word))
```

Also, I can't write Contains in LINQ expression, because it can't parse it to SQL. Which would i write in Where statement?

Comment: To get a better answer, add info about how many elements there are in words and Members (estimates).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to SQL how to do "where \[column\] in (list of values)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075540/linq-to-sql-how-to-do-where-column-in-list-of-values)

Comment: @Henk, for words there are 1-10... It for search, it can't be more, but I don't think that users will search more then 10 words.
For members it growing day by day, so it's a lot)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potentially very expensive brute-force approach:

```
// untested
var names = context.Members.Select(m => m.Name).ToList();
names = names.Where(n => words.Any(w => n.Contains(w));
```

Comment: It less brute-force with doing it without listing, am I right?

context.Members.Where(m=>words.Any(w=>m.Name.Contains(w)))

Comment: I don't know if Linq2Sql will handle the Contains(), that is the reason for the ToList().

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new List<string>();
var b = new List<string>();
var c = a.Where(b.Contains);
```

Comment: Is 'Contains' field of 'b'? Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: a.Where(b.Contains) equals a.Where(x => b.Contains(x)). It projects the Contain method on each element in a.