# How does Linq to SQL perform when using List.Contain()?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have to select some items from a database. The IDs of the items are in a `List`.

In an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1075564/183665), Jon Skeet states that we might use `Contains()`

```c#
var foo = channel.AsQueryable<CodeData>()
                 .Where(codeData => codeIDs.Contains(codeData.CodeId));
```

In a context where the database is huge and the IDs list is really small, how does it perform?

Is Linq smart enough to use the `IN` clause in SQL?

**Edit:** I am using DataContext and SQL Server 2008

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? Try to use SQL Server profiler to see the generated SQL

Comment: The performance mainly depends on your data and which indexes are existing

Comment: As far as I know, EF is smarter with this case than old Linq to SQL.

Comment: @Jan: it will depend on the data and indexes AND the query executed

Comment: @RuiJarimba thanks for the idea. I sadly don't have SQL Server Profiler on my machine. (And the production servers are not up yet :))

Comment: You can do it without a profiler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899974/how-to-view-linq-generated-sql-statements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, LINQ 2 SQL would use the `IN` clause in this scenario.

But not because it is "smart" and detects that you have a huge DB and a small id list.

The `IN` clause is how LINQ 2 SQL "knows" to express the `List.Contains` in SQL.

---

In fact, if you had a list of 1000 items you'll see an `IN` clause with 1000 parameters.

If you have a list of more than 2100 ids, you'll hit a limitation in the SQL Client that does not allow more than 2100 parameters on a command. But LINQ 2 SQL would happily generate a command that has, for example, even 5000 parameters.