# is it possible to get the linq for the following?

Tags: c#, linq

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM tblOrders 
WHERE CustomerId in (3455,4423,7655,1000)
```

**LINQ Query**
 ?

Say, I have an Array of IDs, then how do I search?

```
int[4] _ids;

_ids[0]=3455
_ids[1]=4423
_ids[2]=7655
_ids[3]=1000

 var _orders = (from o in tblOrders 
                where (o.CustomerId in _ids[])
                select o);
```

Above code is just for the example sake, I know it's wrong. But, is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075540/linq-to-sql-how-to-do-where-column-in-list-of-values

Comment: Can you please clarify why -1 because same thing is in accepted answer "lstOrders.FindAll(x => _customers.Any(y =>y == x.CustomerID))".Rest code i placed is just to fill dummy lists for better explaining your example and that could  be removed if not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not.

Try this one:

```
var _orders = from o in tblOrders 
              where _ids.Contains(o.CustomerId)
              select o;
```

The keyword `in` you used, it is used for other purpose in C#. It is not like `IN` in `SQL`.
It is used in `foreach` statements. For instance:

```
foreach(var _id in _ids)
    Console.WriteLine(_id);
```

Also, it is used as a generic modifier, for generic type parameters. For more documentation on the latter, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Contains` method of the _ids array.

```
var _orders = from o in tblOrders
              where _ids.Contains(o.CustomerId)
              select o;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use code as given below

```
        List<Orders> lstOrders = new List<Orders>();
        Orders objOrders;
        for (int index = 1; index <= 10; index++)
        {
            objOrders = new Orders();
            objOrders.OrderID = index;
            objOrders.Order = "Order_" + index.ToString();
            objOrders.CustomerID = index;
            lstOrders.Add(objOrders);
        }


        int[] _customers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        List<Orders> lstFilteredOrders = new List<Orders>();
        lstFilteredOrders.AddRange(lstOrders.FindAll(x => _customers.Any(y =>y == x.CustomerID)));
```