# GetList of records based on list of Id's

Tags: c#, linq

I have this List of IDS

```
var profileID=(PMSdb.Tbl1.Where(x=>x.ID==_ID)).ToList();
```

and I want to Get from database based on this List so I used

```
   var Profiles = new List<Profile>(crmcontext.Profile.Where(x=>profileIDs.Contains(x.Profile_ID)));
```

it works well but 
it will get all Id's which contains this value not the exact value 
for example 
if my `ProfileIDs` list is as
[1,2,5]
and profile Table ID is
[12,1,25,112]

it will get all of them not only ID=1

how can I get this?

Comment: This looks right on the face of it. Contains should check for equality between all elements of the list. Assuming nothing weird and based on the two example arrays this code should work

Comment: @ste-fu Sorry, I can't understand your point, did you mean that it will return only the exact value ? if yes how!! contains function works as `Like` function in SQL

Comment: To me @ste-fu is right, this should work. I thought "contains" would be converted to an "in" clause ...

Comment: According to [this answer by the mighty Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1075564/6838730) your code should work ...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Your code should work perfectly, ignore what is below...

I just tried this in a test project

```
var ids = new List<int>{1, 2, 5, 10, 25};
var targetIds = new List<int>{1, 1010, 5, 10, 255};
var Profiles = targetIds.Where(x=>ids.Contains(x));

foreach(var p in Profiles)
{                
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

and it outputs

```
1
5
10
```

which means it did not take the `1010` value. Are you sure that in your example you get wrong rows ? If you do, it comes from the SQL, not LINQ.

It means that instead if you do the following it should work

```
var Profiles = new List<Profile>(crmcontext.Profile.ToList().Where(x=>profileIDs.Contains(x.Profile_ID)));
```

**WARNING THIS WILL CONVERT YOUR WHOLE TABLE INTO A LIST - DO NOT USE IF THE TABLE CONTAINS LOTS OF DATA**

Comment: note (I'm trying to come up with a better way right now, give me a few minutes)